# Laravel 4 drop down list

Tags: php, laravel

I've made a drop down list that takes 'destination-from' values on 'oneways' table from the database. Following this tutorial here: http://www.laravel-tricks.com/tricks/easy-dropdowns-with-eloquents-lists-method

But whenever I try to run it, It gives me this kind of error: *Undefined variable: categories* What seems to be the problem here? I am really new to this. A newbie on laravel.

Here are my codes:

**onewayflight.blade.php**

```
  $categories = Category::lists('destination-from', 'title');
      {{ Form::select('category', $categories) }}
```

**onewayflightcontroller.php**

```
  public function onewayflightresults()
{
  return View::make('content.onewayflight');

  $list = DB::table('oneways');
  $listname = Oneways::lists('destination-from');

  $content = View::make('content.onewayflight', array('list'=>$list, 'listname'=>$listname));
}
```

I am not really sure of what I have left out one this. And I am also wondering if the model has something to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

The code in your template where you are fetching the categories needs to be surrounded by PHP tags otherwise it won't be executed. But better still - move it to your controller which is where it belongs.

Also in your controller you return the view at the top of your onewayflight() - nothing after this will be executed.

So change it work work like this and you should be ok:

onewayflight.blade.php

```
{{ Form::select('category', $categories) }}
```

onewayflightcontroller.php

```
 public function onewayflight()
 {
    $categories = Category::lists('destination-from', 'title'); 

    return View::make('content.onewayflight', array('categories' => $categories));
  }
```

Also, in routes.php the route should look like this:

```
Route::get('/your-route-path', [
    'as' => 'your_route_name',
    'uses' => 'onewayflightcontroller@onewayflight'
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply sir.
Tried changing this into your suggested solution but it ended up with this error: Undefined variable: categories

Comment: I've updated it, try it now. Make sure that you aren't still returning the view on the first line of onewayflight().

Comment: Still got the same results sir. The error links to the blade template.

Comment: hmm strange, that should work. Can you copy and paste the whole error please?

Comment: Undefined variable: categories (View: C:\wamp\www\airlines\app\views\content\onewayflight.blade.php)

Comment: Is this bit: {{ Form::select('category', $categories) }} the only place you have $categories in your blade template?

Comment: I don't quite get your question sir but if you are asking about if I've declared (or whatever programmers call it) $categories once, then yes.. or you are asking another thing?

Comment: Yes that what I was asking, ok what do you get if you put dd($categories) in your controller after you fetch the categories?

Comment: This is going to sound quite dumb but do you mean like this? dd($categories) = Category::lists('destination-from');

Comment: Nope, leave the line where you fetch the categories as it is. Underneath it put dd($catgeories); on a new line

Comment: I've place this dd($catgeories); below  $categories = .... and still the Undefined variable: categories (View: C:\wamp\www\airlines\app\views\content\onewayflight.blade.php) error would occur

Comment: I'm pretty sure the code in your controller isn't being run, which means it's an issue with the route in your routes.php file. See my updated answer above which shows how to link your route to the controller.

Comment: I have done a bit of changes and change onewayflight to onewayflightresults and I am using this for the route: Route::get('flight/onewayflight','OnewayflightController@onewayflightresults');

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to @jd182 's advice (as I lack the reputation to comment, I use answer); are you sure that lists() function/facade returns some value other than `null`. PHP, sometimes, considers `null` values as undefined.

And your blade syntax is wrong. if you want to define a variable inside a blade file (which is not advised) you should wrap it around  tag and work it as a regular php file.